# Autowire a bean from spring config - Environment specific

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to have environment specific boolean flag. In my spring config, I defined three beans which are environment specific as per below.

```
    <bean id="validationFlag-E1" class="java.lang.Boolean.FALSE"/>
    <bean id="validationFlag-E2" class="java.lang.Boolean.TRUE"/>
    <bean id="validationFlag-E3" class="java.lang.Boolean.TRUE"/>
```

I have also "spring.profiles.active" system property defined at server level and its value is "E1 /E2 /E3" based on the environment.

In my service, i'm trying to do autowiring as per below but it is not working and getting No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Boolean' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Please advise me.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("validationFlag-${spring.profiles.active}")
Boolean evalFlag;
```

We can achieve the above requirement by having individual environment specific property file. But I don't want to create three property files for a single flag. So, trying above approach in my spring framework project.

Comment: Are you using Boot?

Comment: No. Using spring mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your bean definition to:

```
<bean id="validationFlag-E1" class="java.lang.Boolean">
     <constructor-arg value="false"/>
</bean>
    <bean id="validationFlag-E2" class="java.lang.Boolean">
<constructor-arg value="true"/>
</bean>
    <bean id="validationFlag-E3" class="java.lang.Boolean">
<constructor-arg value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Looks like bean definition is correct. I don't see any XML model errors.
But getting No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Boolean' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. How can we resolve this?

Comment: In your @Qualifier not getting value for the placeholder -${spring.profiles.active} because of that you are getting this error if you want profile specific bean means you have to define like this                        <beans profile="E1">
  <bean id="validationFlag" class="java.lang.Boolean.False"/>
 </beans>                                                                                                                                   <beans profile="E2">
  <bean id="validationFlag" class="java.lang.Boolean.True"/>
 </beans>

Answer (score 1):

You can use environmental property `${blah.blah.flag}` (or whatever name you choose) with value of a flag (`false` or `true`) `-Dblah.blah.flag=true` and then inject that value as a property

```
@Value("${blah.blah.flag}")
private Boolean flag;
```

Comment: We can do that way but it would end up creating environment specific property file in total 3 files. I'm not interested in creating multiple files only for this single flag. So, trying the above approach.

Comment: What do you mean by specific property file? Instead of spring.profiles active you pass that flag

Comment: flag-E1.properties
flag-E2.properties
, flag-E3.properties

Comment: As I've said you do not need a properties file to pass properties ro Spring. You can use system and environmental properties for that